# How can I check if an object inherits from another class using FluentAssertions?

Tags: c#, xunit, fluent-assertions

I would like to know how can I check if an object inherits from another class using Fluent Assertions?

I know I can do that with xUnit using `IsAssignableFrom`, like so:

```
[Fact]
public void CreateBossEnemy()
{
    //arrange
    EnemyFactory sut = new EnemyFactory();

    //action
    var enemy = sut.Create("Zombie King", true);

    //assert
    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<Enemy>(enemy);
}
```

What would be the equivalent of `IsAssignableFrom` for Fluent Assertions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To check whether `enemy` is assignable to the the type `Enemy` you can use:

```cs
enemy.Should().BeAssignableTo<Enemy>();
```

Some resources:

- [documentation](https://fluentassertions.com/basicassertions/)
- [source code](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/blob/f60927f3c55afac2288f6f9fc9b527da619c40e2/Src/FluentAssertions/Primitives/ReferenceTypeAssertions.cs#L235)
- [tests](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/blob/f60927f3c55afac2288f6f9fc9b527da619c40e2/Tests/Shared.Specs/ObjectAssertionSpecs.cs#L395)